# Construct a fractional linear map $\phi=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$, $c\neq0$ such that $\phi(\phi(\phi(z)))=z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Construct a fractional linear map $\phi=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$, $c\neq0$ such that $\phi(\phi(\phi(z)))=z$

Knowing that three compositions produces the identity, my initial thought is that it is either the $\phi$ is the identity mapping itself, or $\phi$ is some sort of Blaschke factor that rotates a point by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. But I don't have any concrete idea to go along with it.

Comment: Geometrically you can use the fact that Möbius transformations act transitively in the set of 3 points of the Riemann sphere so you can find the one corresponding to the cyclic rotation of the set $\{0,1,\infty\}$. Algebraically composition of Möbius transformations correspond to the matrix multiplication of its coefficients (because they are element of $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb{C}))$ so you can translate the problem into a system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

The identity implies $\phi^2(z)=\phi^{-1}(z)$. Computing both sides gives:
$$ \frac{(a^2+bc)z+ab+bd}{(ca+dc)z+cb+d^2}=\frac{dz-b}{-cz+a}$$
Equating the coefficients and assuming $a=0$ and $c=1$ gives $b=d$ and $d=-1$ so $\phi(z)=(1-z)^{-1}$

Comment: How can you assume $a$ is 0?

Comment: Equating coefficients will give you 4 equations in 4 unknowns. You can solve all of them for $a,b,c,d$, but that can be tedious. Instead, to simplify $a^2+bc=d$, you can try to skip the work and say $a=0$ and $c=1$. This might not always work, but it does here, giving $b=d$ and $bd=-b$, which can be solved easily and yield valid values for $\phi$.

Comment: Interesting. In what circumstances can we assume such things?

Comment: Whenever it leads to valid solutions. If you have a complicated set of equations, you can try some simplifying assumptions, solve the simpler problem, and check if the results make sense. If they don't, then your assumptions were wrong and you must go back and either make less assumptions or just solve the problem in full.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of coefficients must cube to a scalar multiple of the identity, such as $\pm I$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0& 1 \\
-1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Note that this is the "[companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)" for $\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1$

The fact that there is an integer two by two matrix that cubes to the identity is a standard ingredient in the [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group). For example, see page 9 in Binary Quadratic Forms by Duncan Buell.

Many authors use the transposed version of the companion matrix. In that case, the answer agrees with that of Guacho Perez

Comment: Would you please explain a little bit more? How did you come up with that matrix first of all? And what is the companion matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It's a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). In matrix representation, we need that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b\\
    c & d
\end{bmatrix}^3=I$$

Comment: I’m aware of that. But computing left hand side produces a monstrous expression.